# How to pack a snapshot of a local dependency in a published package

Tags: npm, package, publish, monorepo, rush

In a JavaScript monorepo managed with [Rush](https://rushjs.io/), I have three projects:

- `backend/`
- `frontend/`
- `shared/`

In `backend/package.json` and `frontend/package.json`, the `shared` project is declared as a dependency:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "shared": "0.0.0",
```

In the local environment, everything works fine, thanks to Rush, which runs `npm link` for me.

Now I need to publish.

On the `frontend` project, the command `rushx build` (like `npm run build`) creates JS and CSS bundles with the help of webpack, and puts them in the `backend/` directory.

I would like to publish the `backend` project as a real package on npmjs. I don't want to publish `shared` as a distinct package because in the published version it is not shared anymore. The `shared` content is already bundled in the frontend. I would like to embed it into the backend too.

I tried to pack it:

```sh
cd backend/
npm pack ../shared
# A new file is created: 'shared-0.0.0.tgz'
```

Then I edited `backend/package.json`:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "shared": "shared-0.0.0.tgz",
```

But after that the generated package doesn't work. When I execute `npm install my-published-package`, it tries to find `shared-0.0.0.tgz` in the current directory instead of the installed package directory.

Is there an elegant solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the full relative path to `shared-0.0.0.tgz`, [as documeted here](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#local-paths):

```
  "dependencies": {
    "shared": : "file:~/some/relative/path/shared-0.0.0.tgz"
```

The valid relative paths can be anything like these (use whatever is appropriate for your structure):

```
../foo/bar
~/foo/bar
./foo/bar
/foo/bar
```

Then do `rush install` or `rush update` to process the change.

If that doesn't work, try saving the shared package with `npm install --save` first.

If that doesn't work, [bundledDependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bundleddependencies) may be the answer. I'll build up a test project tonight to try it out and update later, but this may get you on your way sooner.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know `bundleddependencies`. This may be the way to go indeed.

Comment: I tested with `bundledDependencies`. It works but there is a huge issue: `shared` is not correctly packed. It is just bundled _as it is_, with source files, `.rush/` and `node_modules/` directories etc. The script `prepublish` of `shared/package.json` is ignored. The file `.npmignore` and the `"files"` section in `package.json` as well. Under these conditions, I can't use this feature.

Comment: Try moving the `prepublish` script to `prepack`.